# Is there a way to create a new column using another column as a filter and a further column as the value inputs on SQL?

Tags: oracle, transpose

Essentially I have a table produced on Oracle SQL:

| LEVEL | NAME | GDP | EXP BC | EXP CC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | AFF_B_BCORE | 88956.83 | 67063.51 | 15136.50 |
| C | AFF_C_CCORE | 84858.36 | 0 | 0 |
| J | AFF_J_CCORE | 78115.38 | 77177.73 | 23501.13 |
| B | AFF_OTHER | 12740.93 | 0 | 0 |
| C | AFF_OTHER | 11121.93 | 0 | 0 |
| J | AFF_OTHER | 15762.48 | 0 | 0 |

But I want to create a column to combine the NAME & GDP related to the column name following it ie. GDP_B_BCORE and GDP_C_CCORE with the values of the corresponding GDP. The same to be applied to EXP BC and EXP CC.

I've tried to CASE and SUM(CASE to no avail.

I want my output to be like:

| GDP_B_BCORE | GDP_C_CCore | GDP_J_JCORE | EXP BC | EXP CC | EXP JC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 88956.83 | 84858.36 | 78115.38 | 67063.51 | 15136.50 | 77177.73 |

Something like this.

Comment: Please edit your question and share the expected output as text, also share the query you have tried so far

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,for%20users%20with%20visual%20impairments.)

Comment: Would this help? https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-pivot/

Comment: What happened to value `23501.13`? Are `AFF_OTHER` values in `NAME` filtered out? What happens if there is an `AFF_K_CCORE` added to the data, should the result expand to include 2 or 3 more columns? I guess, my questions are coming from this: I see 10 non-0 values, but your desired results contain 6. Why?

Comment: Hi JNevill, the 77000 value contains the 23501.13 hence it would be disregarded due to duplication. The AFF_OTHER  has its own filter but for now I'm focusing on the main objectives.  Ultimately yes it will expand to fit the OTHER columns but for now its not a priority as I presume  it will be the same method. The 0 values are due to a previous filter within the dataset. EDIT: I've amended the table so its more clear the filters